# Display label (span) no mouse hover

Tags: html, css

I am creating a bar with icons with content on its side:
http://plnkr.co/edit/g6bOXcskIHEWdwp7ZRRW?p=preview

When the mouse is over an icon I want the name to appear in front of the icon and over the content. But is showing under the icon.

How can I fix this?

**Markup**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
          <span>One</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
          <span>Two</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    This is the content</br>
    Span of icon should be over content when mouse is over
  </div>        
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.navigation {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
}  
.content {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
ul { 
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
a {
  background-color: #d0d0d0;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
a:hover span {
  display: inline-block;
}
a span {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

add `width:100%` to `a:hover`

```
a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}
```

and add `width:0` & `vertical-align:top`(optional) to `a:hover span`

```
a:hover span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 0;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/g4P7JfGCmqbyyZqnkCcp?p=preview)**

Comment: This was the only suggestion that worked as intended. Thank you

Comment: After testing it a little bit more your solution does not work. I mean works in Plunker but if I test it in a page on my project it stops working. Then I tested it on Plunker Embed View: http://embed.plnkr.co/g6bOXcskIHEWdwp7ZRRW/preview ... And here it does not work either. Any idea why?

Comment: the embed you just showed me doesn't have my code on it. if you apply it then it will work  (I just tested it using dev tools)

Comment: There is a problem with your code when using box-sizing: border-box ... It stops working ... Is it possible to convert your code in a way that works with box-sizing: border-box?

Comment: I was able to solve the boder-box problem but when the span contains longer text it becomes in more then one line which is not supposed. Place the mouse over the second icon in http://plnkr.co/edit/gWB6O68x9UcfduWflzOq?p=preview

Comment: sorry for the delay,[this](http://plnkr.co/edit/TQ2MYWxMxw7Rg881fOx7?p=preview) is how I managed to solve `border-box` issue, I couldn't see multiple lines though

Answer (score 1):

You are putting the title of the button "one" and "two" under the list item
So it is putting the icon in a list item, and then displaying the content under.

Try putting it inside of the list item like i did below!

This should fix  your problem and display the icon and then the name of the icon! If you would like some separation, just add a little margin to the title of the icon! 
Hope this was helpful!

```
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
           <i class="fa fa-home"><span>One</span></i>
        </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
           <i class="fa fa-book"><span>Two</span></i>
        </a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure you have no whitespace in between the tags. Add a margin-left to the span class to separate icon and title in the same line!

Comment: That increases the width of all ul

Answer (score 0):

I've made edits to your code and included comments for each line added or removed. I hope this is your intended effect:

Change your link CSS to:

```
a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  position: relative;    /* So the span's position: absolute; keeps relative to the icon */
}
```

Change your span CSS to:

```
a:hover span {
  /*display: inline-block;   Not needed */
  position: absolute;     /* Make the text able to float over icon */
  top:35%;                /* Place the text near the vertical-middle of the icon */
  left:100%;              /* Place the text outside the icon menu */
  padding-left:10px;      /* The spacing from the icon menu */
  color: #000;            /* So we can see it */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add following to your css file

```
a:hover{
  width:50px;
  z-index:1001;
  position:relative;
}
```